# Lwuit on nokia. Setting a command to the game fire key

Tags: java-me, command, nokia, lwuit

This may seem trivial, but i'm working on a project  to be deployed exclusively on nokia phones, and all i want is to create a command and set it to the "GAME_FIRE" center key. For some reason, when adding lwuit commands, LWUIT skips the game fire key, and instead creates a defaut menu command that then shows the added commands. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Display.getInstance().setThirdSoftButton(true);
```

This will set the label on the fire key as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, LWUIT never uses the center key to commands. It wont event let you have two menus,it will always use  one soft key for the main (the first) command, and all the other commands will be on a menu in the other soft button

Comment: It seems i'll just use the default menu command that lwuit automatically provides, the other option would be to find that keys particular keycode and then assign it to a command event on the form and still have to find a way of pasting the command's label directly on top of the center soft key(sounds messy) Thanks.

Comment: LWUIT is both open source and well designed (and coded!), so you probably can do what you think without getting really messy... but it will take you some time.